# Import a node module in Vue.js CLI instance

Tags: vue.js

I've created a new vue app using `vue init webpack sample-app` .

I'm trying to import this module (https://docs.botui.org/install.html) into my `app.vue` and make it show on.

What's the correct way to import this module into a Vue.JS app?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal in your project root folder, then install the package:

```
npm install botui --save
```

Then open `src/main.js` in your text editor and add this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BotUI from 'botui'

const botui = BotUI('my-botui-app', {
  vue: Vue // pass the dependency.
})
```

This will create a botui instance. But that instance won't have any messages in it. You can check that it's working by adding a message:

```
botui.message.bot('Hello, how can I help?')
```

Comment: I did that. Then in App.vue, I added this <div id="my-botui-app"><bot-ui></bot-ui></div> . I created a simple my-botui-app.js that initiates 'var botui = new BotUI('my-botui-app');'

But it still doesn't show up. Any idea?